# What does the number "1" next to the "class" Babel icon and the "field/variable" icon mean in Visual C# 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, express, icons, babeljs

I am new to Visual C# 2010 Express. I am trying to learn what the Babel icons mean.

So far the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=VS.100).aspx has answered all of my questions -- except for one:

When I look in the "Locals" window while I am debugging, both the Babel icons for "class" and "field/variable" have a very small numeral "1" inside a square box next to the icon at the very left/bottom.

I can't seem to find any information about what this "1" inside a square box means.

I have a screen shot but this site will not allow me to post it because I am a new member.

Your help is very much appreciated!

All the best,

Brian S.

Comment: I'm guessing you are talking about the lock.  The part where you insert the key looks like a small white 1.  Means private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means **`static`** member. For example in the class:

```
class Elephant
{
  public int I;
  public static int J;
}
```

the field `J` is `static` which means there is only ONE such field even if you create many `Elephant`. In contrast, there is an `I` for every `Elephant`, i.e. "many".

Comment: Thank you, Jeppe! That does indeed answer my question. It's so difficult for me to believe that I can't find any information on this question through a search engine. I guess I'm the first to ever ask about this(??). Appreciate the help! All the best, Brian Sussman

Comment: @BrianSussman You can "accept" my answer by setting the check mark `✔` to the left. That indicates that the answer solved your problem. It could well be that you're the first to ever ask this. Hopefully your question will now turn up on Google.